# IAR compiler C dialect set to C99 to access the 'dlib' but is still accessing 'clib'

Tags: c99, iar

I have a project with an application and a bootloader running on IAR version 7.12.1. For the most part these are the same and access the same files with the exception of a few. I have IAR project "C/C++ Compiler"->"Language 1"->"C dialect"->"C99" such that I am accessing the 'dlib' and not the 'clib.' I have no issue with my 'application'. However, when I compile my 'bootloader' I keep getting:

Fatal Error[Pe1696]: cannot open source file "stdint.h"

....

searched:"A_path...\inc\clib"

So clearly it is still trying to access the clib and not the dlib. I have also tried directly adding the path to the 'dlib' in the "C/C++ Compiler"->"Preprocessor" tab. However, I think this is confusing the compiler because now it is finding two "stdint.h" files. I have also tried ensuring that the project options between the application and bootloader match, but I am still encountering this problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. I had the wrong library selected under "General Options" -> "Library Configuration".